# Does serialization occurr when passing objects between Activitys and Fragments?

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, bundle

I have a class `Crop` that throws a NotSerializableException when it is passed through an intent to another `Activity`. But if it is from an `Activity` to a `Fragment` (through `Bundles`), there's no error and I can see the drawable object in the other side with no errors whatsoever.

How can it be serializable in one case but not in the other ?

```
public class Crop implements Serializable {

    private String specieHarvest;
    private String specieLocation;
    private String specieName;
    private Drawable img;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's answer your question.

The reason of the behavior you are seeing is that

- Passing objects as extras to an `activity`, will always cause that object to be marshaled/un-marshaled by Android, it is thought of as some kind of IPC.
- Passing objects as arguments to a `fragment` will not always cause your object to be marshaled.

**Then when is your object taken apart and reconstructed by Android when sent to a fragment?**

It will **not** be serialized/de-serialized **unless** the fragment is destroyed and recreated for some reason, otherwise, that object is kept in a map and the same object is returned to you when you call `getArguments().`

If you even change that object in the `Fragment`, it will change the original one that was sent, because it is in fact the same reference. CRAZY, right? :)

If you take a look at `Drawable` class, you will find that it is not `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, so don't pass it along in intents/arguments.

Instead, pass an int which can be the resource ID if the `Drawable` object is in your resources, or you can pass a `String` path if that is an image that is stored locally somewhere.

Also, passing int or string is much better, because `Drawables` tend to be large is size, which might cause your app to crash due to size exceeded for an intent extras.

[Here's](https://medium.com/@hamidgh/sending-objects-to-fragment-naive-question-is-it-sent-by-value-ddaaa19fa42d) an article where you can read about that as well.

Comment: So that's what it was! Thank you! I was having a bug related to this mechanics. In this post:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980425/parcelable-encountered-ioexception-writing-serializable-object-when-i-dont-seri). I face the issue that made me write this question. I know the answer now: When I try to start another Activity, my MainActivity gets destroyed and so the Fragment that was attached to her, causing the strange serialization exception. If you wish, you can answer it aswell and I' ll mark it correct one more time. Thanks @elmorabea

Comment: You can add the answer to you other question, so if people face the same issue they find the answer :)